# verifying a signed nft swap order

Tags: ethers.js, 0x

I am using [swap sdk](https://github.com/trader-xyz/nft-swap-sdk/tree/main/src/sdk/v3) to verify nft swap order in polygon chain.

```
const pKey = new ethers.Wallet.createRandom();
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(pKey, provider);
const nftSwapSdk = new NftSwapV3(provider, signer, 137);
const result = nftSwapSdk.verifyOrderSignature(
  order,
  order.signature,
  137,
  "0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff"
);
```

the result is always false.
the order is valid.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Trader's Swap SDK but it seems you're trying to use V3 orders but `0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff` is the address of the V4 Exchange on Polygon. There is no official V3 exchange on polygon.

Answer (score 0):

If you join us in #dev-help channel on Discord (https://discord.com/channels/879789553060282388/915257624050663495), happy to walk you through validating a 0x v4 order (or v3 if you prefer)!

tl;dr if you're using v4, be sure to `import { NftSwapV4 } from '@traderxyz/nft-swap-sdk` instead of V3 (the current default).

Comment: Is this an official channel? I've no problem with social networks but an unnamed link is easy to replace for a malicious one, since anyone can edit an answer I'd suggest to add that link to your profile and remove it from the answer.